# Converting Monthly data to weekly data using Multi Index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a data frame as follows.

```
pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020-08-01','2020-08-01','2020-09-01'],'value':[10,12,9],'item':['a','d','b']})
```

I want to convert this to weekly data keeping all the columns apart from the Date column constant.

Expected output

```
pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020-08-01','2020-08-08','2020-08-15','2020-08-22','2020-08-29','2020-08-01','2020-08-08','2020-08-15','2020-08-22','2020-08-29','2020-09-01','2020-09-08','2020-09-15','2020-09-22','2020-09-29'],
          'value':[10,10,10,10,10,12,12,12,12,12,9,9,9,9,9],'item':['a','a','a','a','a','d','d','d','d','d','b','b','b','b','b']})
```

It should be able to convert any month data to weekly data. Date in the input data frame is always the first day of that month. How do I make this happen?
I guess we will have to use Multi-Index for this?. Is there any better way?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you just need to repeat your data 4 times and adjust the date properly:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

(df.loc[df.index.repeat(4)]
   .assign(Date=lambda x: x['Date'] + pd.to_timedelta(np.tile(np.arange(4),len(df)), 
                                                      unit='W') )
)
```

Output:

```
        Date  value item
0 2020-08-01     10    a
0 2020-08-08     10    a
0 2020-08-15     10    a
0 2020-08-22     10    a
1 2020-08-01     12    d
1 2020-08-08     12    d
1 2020-08-15     12    d
1 2020-08-22     12    d
2 2020-09-01      9    b
2 2020-09-08      9    b
2 2020-09-15      9    b
2 2020-09-22      9    b
```